# Prevent LDV-problems in own ISV package by auto-indexing packaged fields

Tags: managed-package, isv, bestpractice, largedatavolumes

In our managed ISV package we have a custom object that in many customer orgs might run into LDV issues as the nature of this object lead to million of records.

I know that Salesforce support can

- index certain fields
- create skinny tables
- increase timeout limits

to prevent most of them, but only per customer org.

**Is there any way to auto enable/disable those feature for all customers of our package?**

Comment: Skinny tables only help speed up join performance. If you only have one table that's going to be huge they probably won't be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer (Safe Harbour) in this recent [Inside the Force.com Query Optimizer Webinar](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mrOzUcycqZM#t=52m27s)

Salesforce.com seems to plan that **custom indexes can be delivered as part of a managed package** without the need to index and optimize each customer org. Nice!

Answer (score 3):

No, these features are intended to be manual activation only. You can usually request these features on behalf of your customer through the partner portal. These settings are *recommended* to not be used until they would provide a positive impact, as indexing and skinny tables introduce additional DML and querying overhead.

Comment: Indexing is *highly* data specific, so this is good advice. Also, you can force indexing on some field types by making it external ID.